# compiling tex files with xelatex is insanely slow on my Windows machine

Tags: xetex, windows

I try to compile a document that is written in Chinese using `xelatex`. But I find that the compiling speed is insanely slow: after about 1.14 minute, the final pdf file is generated. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
 测试
\end{document}
```

If I change the Chinese version to English version (e.g., simply replace 「测试」 with "test"), it makes no difference and the compiling time is more or less the same.

If I comment out `\usepackage{xeCJK}` and compile the English version using `pdflatex`. The compilation speed is fast (around 1.5 seconds).

How to solve this problem?
Ps, I am using a Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: see the thread here http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-March/039768.html  and try using fc-cache as described there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks, I did not see that post previously. Perhaps I should use some alternative keywords to retrieve that post :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some search in the internet and tex.sx, I finally know the cause.
I have installed a new font into my computer a few days ago but have not run the `fc-cache` program. Following the post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327350/114857), here is the solution: go the directory where the Texlive bin resides (in my computer, it is `D:\texlive\2016\bin\win32`) and execute `fc-cache -f` (if `fc-cache` is on system PATH, then you do not have to go to that directory.). It should takes a few seconds or minutes. Then open the cmd and compile your tex file again, you will find that the compiling time is acceptable now.

Also, I have verified that we should run `fc-cache -f` every time a font is installed or removed. Then the compiling time using `xelatex` should be normal.

Comment: I had to use `fc-cache -f` to force the recreation. `fc-cache` alone didn't work for me. And if you call fc-cache on a command line you don't have to go to the bin-folder, like the other tools, fc-cache is in your path.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, on my computer, simply execute `fc-cache.exe` works. But I do agree that using `fc-cache -f` is safer :)

Comment: I don't doubt that it worked for you ;-). I only added the comment in case someone else has to use `-f` to.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I have updated the answer according to your suggestions.

Comment: I need to run `fc-cache.exe` as administrator on my Windows 7 machine for it to work properly. And sometimes I need to run it even though I haven't (un)installed any fonts. At seemingly random times `xelatex` runs slow and this fixes my problem, regardless of whether or not I'm using `fontspec` and friends.

Comment: I have a full installation of MiKTeX 2.9, and my bin\x64 folder doesn't have any fc-cache.exe. What do I do?

Comment: @JasperMay Use TexLive.

Comment: Ok thank you. So XeLaTex doesn't work with MiKTeX at all? Is there no way to have 'special characters' in the code in MiKTeX?