# Fontspec slows everything down

Tags: xetex, compiling, fontspec, texmaker

I've been using TeXLive and Texmaker 4.5 with XeLateX, and the use of the fontspec package slows everything down.

More precisely, it takes 21 seconds to compile this :

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

---

If I take out the `\usepackage{fontspec}`, it takes no more than a second.

1. What can I do ? What are the alternatives ?
2. Can it be related to the fact that on texmaker parameters , my DVI viewer is MikTeX (it says "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/yap.exe" %.dvi) ? Seems strange to me since I installed and am using TeXLive. I don't remember installing MikTex, but it's not impossible. What is the correct path if I want to use TeXlive ? Just the main TeXLive folder ?

As you can tell, I'm a beginner and non-english speaker, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Which texlive version are you using? 2016 had a bug regarding fc-cache. Try to run `fc-cache -f` on a command line.

Comment: Thank you for your time. @TeXnician : I don't know how to run xelatex with anything else then TeXmaker. Terminal makes me think of linux but I'm using Windows.

Comment: @David Carlisle : the first log line says : "This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.11.2) 13 NOV 2017 17:36". So it's 2016 I guess, and fontspec actually does something ? About xunicode I'm not sure it's useful, I wasn't arrived to that line yet !

Comment: @David Carlisle : Ok, got it, it says : "LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3"

Comment: @TeXnician : I managed the CMD part, and one line takes much more time than any other, it's : (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def). Useful ?

Comment: @Kempermaz OK that is an older release where without fontspec you are using the same fonts as pdflatex, but fontspec switches the default to opentype. Recent releases (after 2017/01/01) default to opentype so fontspec as used in your test should have very little effect

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer : I'm using TeXlive 2016 (the log says LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>), and tried to run "fc-cache -f" like you said, but had little results (maybe 2 seconds less).

Comment: Not really the new default is to do essentially what fontspec was making the default so if you update, adding fontspec won't make it slow, but it'll be slow anyway (unless you can find out why the font loading is slow) of course it may be that an update would fix that (did you run fc-cache as Ulrike suggested)

Comment: If it stops at the eu1enc.def it is quite probably the fc-cache problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357100/2388

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did run fc-cache with little result. The problem seems to come from the "(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)" line in the CMD, like I said to TeXnician, I don't know if that gives you ideas.

Comment: @Kempermaz that's the file that causes latex to switch to open type fonts, at which point the font searching on your machine seems unreasonably slow, fc-cache is supposed to cache the search and make it quick  but hard to know what to suggest. You could update to texlive 2017 see if that is better.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it's fast now ! The fc-cache solution was the right one, I just had to execute it in the right directory (...\texlive\2016\bin\win32). I have more questions now then before, but one thing at a time, at least it's working now.

Comment: @David Carlisle : yes, it is, that's where I found the details about the fc-cache solution. I don't know if those two subjects can be linked somehow. I also don't know how to mark my question as "solved". Feel free to do so if you have the rights. And thanks again.